# Draw rhombus with the format specifier "%*.*s" of printf()

Tags: c, printf

I'm trying to encode a small program to print me a rhomb on screen using the standard printf until now I have this code which as you will see when compiling does not print the desired output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, n = 5;
    for(i = -n/2; i < n; i++)
    printf("%*.*s\n", n / 2 + 1, i, "*****");
    return 0;
}
```

can someone tell me how it should be this?

desired output:

[image]

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: I edited my question to add image

Comment: Since the output requires 9 consecutive `*` asterisks and the code has only 5, you are doomed to failure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

another option:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    for (int n = 11, i = -n / 2; i < n / 2 + 1; i++)
        printf("%*.*s\n", n - abs(i), 1 + (n / 2 - abs(i)) * 2, "***********");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, a superior answer, I didn't know you could truncate a string this way.

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() { 
 for(int i=1;i<10;i++)
   printf("%.*s%.*s\n",abs(5-i),"            ",9-abs(10-(i<<1)),"**********");
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, a superior answer, I didn't know you could truncate a string this way.

Comment: This 'cheats' by using two `%.*s` conversion specifications, instead of one `%*.*s`. but it can be done with just the one conversion specification.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yeah, I didn't either, or at least didn't remember it. This question is good for the reason that we get to learn by answering it.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers demonstrate how to solve the problem with funky math. The alternative is to solve the problem with a software state machine. The state machine has three state variables

- skip -- the number of spaces at the beginning of the line
- show -- the number of asterisks (stars) shown on the line
- delta -- used to adjust skip and show on each pass through the loop

This arrangement of state variables makes the printf much easier to understand. `skip+show` is the total number of characters on a line, `show` is the number of asterisks to take from the `stars` string, and the `stars` string just has to be longer than the maximum value of `show`.

```
char *stars = "*********************";
printf( "%*.*s\n", skip + show, show, stars );
```

So the questions are how to update the state variables on each pass through the loop, and what is the loop termination condition.

Taking the example where `n=5`, the sequence of values for `skip` is

```
4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4
```

We accomplish this by initially setting `skip = n-1` and `delta = -1`. Adding `delta` to `skip` causes `skip` to decrement till it reaches `0`. Instead of allowing `skip` to go negative, we force `skip = 1` and `delta = 1` to change directions. Then `skip` increments until it reaches `n`, which terminates the loop.

The sequence of values for `show` is

```
1 3 5 7 9 7 5 3 1
```

This sequence is generated by starting with `show=1`, and adjusting by `-2*delta`.

```
char *stars = "*********************";

int n = 5;
int skip = n - 1;
int delta = -1;
int show = 1;
while ( skip < n )
{
    printf( "%*.*s\n", skip + show, show, stars  );

    skip += delta;
    if ( skip < 0 )
    {
        skip = 1;
        delta = 1;
    }

    show -= delta * 2;
}
```